# "Call require API level..." from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio

I am trying to use ThreadLocalRandom.current() in my GAE endpoint via Android Studio, but getting this error:

Call requires API level 21 (current min is 1)

ThreadLocalRandom is not even an Android API library!

Does anyone have any idea?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Johnny, were you able to resolve?

Comment: @Enoobong...yes and no...the API call works fine despite the error.

Comment: Yeah noticed that it works, just wanted to get the red mark off

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following annotation on top of whatever method your `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` line is contained in:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.L)
```

For example:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.L)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
}
```